# How to annotate a class method parameter with the class it self

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this error message `Unresolved reference 'TreeNode'` on `def add_children(self, child: TreeNode)` I think this an IDE (PyCharm) issue. The code run's well.

I don't understand why, and how can I fix it?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(
        self,
        element: Entity,
        children=None
    ):
        if children is None:
            self.children = []
        else:
            self.children = children
        self.element = element

    def add_children(self, child: TreeNode):
        self.children.append(child)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeNode` is only defined after the `class TreeNode` body. Use `from __future__ import annotations` or `child: 'TreeNode'` to make a forward reference.

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(
        self,
        element: Entity,
        children=None
    ):
        if children is None:
            self.children = []
        else:
            self.children = children
        self.element = element

    def add_children(self, child: 'TreeNode'):
        self.children.append(child)
```